# Vue propagate event to child element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some html that renders these little boxes:

[image: ui]

```
<div class="token-checkboxes">
  <span class="checkbox-span" v-for="token_obj in token_to_vue_obj">
    <input v-on:change="plot()" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="token_obj.show">
    <label for="checkbox">{{ token_obj.token }}</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

I want the effect from clicking on the outer pill element (the grey background area) to be the same as the effect from clicking on the checkbox itself. Is there a simple way to "forward" an event on a parent element to a child or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event listener on the outer pill element to change the model value. This isn't really forwarding an event but it should have the same effect (clicking the pill toggles the checkbox).

```
<span class="checkbox-span"
      v-for="token_obj in token_to_vue_obj"
      v-on:click="token_obj.show = !token_obj.show; plot()">
```

**Edit** (see comments): Remove `plot()` from the `<input>` element's change handler to prevent the `plot()` function being called twice if you click the checkbox.

Check out the snippet below.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.token-checkboxes',
  methods: {
    plot() {
      console.log('Plot called!');
    }
  },
  data: {
    token_to_vue_obj: [
      { token: '_#misc',  show: true },
      { token: '_#study', show: true },
      { token: '_#code',  show: true },
      { token: '_#debug', show: true },
      { token: '_data',   show: false }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.checkbox-span {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="token-checkboxes">
  <span class="checkbox-span"
        v-for="token_obj in token_to_vue_obj"
        v-on:click="token_obj.show = !token_obj.show;plot()"
        v-bind:key="token_obj.token">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" v-model="token_obj.show">
    <label for="checkbox">{{ token_obj.token }}</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

---

**Edit**: see comment below. The non-unique `id="checkbox"` causes problems.

Comment: Yeah this works. Thanks! But in your snippet, every time I click on any span the first checkbox toggles. I have no idea why.

Comment: @JesseAldridge Wow, that is weird. I'm on it!

Comment: @JesseAldridge Found it! Change the `id="checkbox"`. Seems that Vue might be using ids behind the scenes to try to change model attributes, and having the same id for multiple elements causes the first one to always change. (E.g., changing it to `class="checkbox"` fixed things).

Comment: Dang, thanks again. I never would've figured that one out.

Comment: It's not that Vue is doing something behind the scenes, but javascript. When selecting by Id JS only cares about returning one, so it will return the first one it finds, giving you intended behaviour. Obviously, the fix here was to use classes :)

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly I'm aware, but the thing I find strange is that Vue seems to use *OP's id* somewhere (in addition to its own, probably auto-generated id), otherwise the first element wouldn't have been toggled. If it never has to use OP's id this problem wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Er, actually, it seems this doesn't quite work. The checkbox toggles, but plot doesn't actually get called unless you click the checkbox itself.

Comment: @JesseAldridge Sorry! If you move the `plot()` method to be called from the `<span>`'s click handler instead of the `<input>`'s change handler (not the other way around to prevent duplication of the event), it should work.

Comment: Yep, there we go.